# CodeIgniter [CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException]

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am beginner of CodeIgniter 4.when i installed and run the project using following command **php spark serve** i got the error

```
[CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException]

The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: intl.

at SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php:228
```

what i tried so far. i set the path **C:\xampp\php** and ran but same error displayed.
and i tried to install composer and run it but same error displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced same issue and resolve following below steps:

go to the app=> Config => Boot => production.php in your project

Change the ini_set('display_errors', '0') to ini_set('display_errors', '1') above will show you the error detail then do the following:

Open [xampp_folder_path]/php/php.ini to edit.

Search for ;extension=intl and remove the ;.

Save the php.ini file and restart Apache.

reference/thanks to: Chibueze Agwu and mail2bapi

Comment: Thanks working for me.